# ClassNotFoundException in build path jar in run time

Tags: java

My team exported a jar from java project which having classes and jars in that lib.

I got that jar from my team and just add that jar using build path as external jar in my project.

I got an error while create an object for a class(`canon.class`) in that jar file, from my project **controller** class.

it says

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.Context
```

while this class is in other jar file is also in the build path.

I am not sure why this happens. Can anyone give me assistance in this?

Comment: 1. That means your jar file not available in that build path. Please recheck again whether it is there or not. 2. Might be your jar file is corrupted. If you have any Compile time errors in your code then jar file will be corrupted

Comment: All jars available in target library..

Comment: are You saying that You got a jar with jars in it?

Comment: maslan, I got all the jars separately in targer lib

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "target library"?

Comment: And how do You run it? Using java -jar? Or some IDE?

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the logback.jar is on the classpath. That should solve it.

Comment: Yes, its availabe.... When I used as simple java project with these jar I am able to run.. When I used in my maven project it says the error..

Comment: Do you have added it to your pom.xml as a dependency?